# Does Parse limit on amount of relational data returned?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, relationship

As I understand it, [Parse limits the amount of rows returned by a query to 100 by default and a hard limit of 1000 maximum if set in the code.](https://parse.com/questions/parse-only-returns-100-objects-of-data)

I am creating some cloud code with a query to get some blog posts. I've had to create a join table between the user and the blog posts so that I know which users have viewed the posts (other options were not a possibility).

Lets imagine Parse had a limit of 3 results returned per request.

The user has viewed blog posts A, B, C, D.

My query returns blog posts A, B, D.

I assume the query would look something like this:

```
var userViewBlog = new Parse.Query(parse.UserViewBlog);
userViewBlog.equalTo("user", user);

var blogQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Blog);
blogQuery.doesNotMatchQuery("blog",userViewBlog());
```

How will I know if the user has viewed all of these posts? The join table will need to return 4 rows for me to be sure I have gathered all of the blog views, but the relational query could return just A, B, C from the join table due to the 3 row limit.

Is there a proper way to do this that Im missing? Essentially I would like to know if [parse relations](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#relations) have the same limit as a normal query.

Comment: To display every data you will have to make use of [`skip(n)`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#skip) and [`limit(n)`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#limit) to load your data by chunk.

Comment: This is what I was worried about. Would it be a far better solution to store viewed blogs on the User object?

Comment: Comment length limit ... see answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is really only the way you choose to display it.
Parse is a framework to get the data with ease for multiplateform. You surely don't want to load all your user's viewed blog if it is more than 1000, it will be quite long to fetch and also to display.

One common design is to display a small chunk, and *when* the user saw the last piece (detected with javascript), fetch the next chunk. For the user it's transparent as they only see your data in a continuous way. You can see this design in use for facebook/twitter/instagram where when the end of the page is reached, they load more data.

The other but less dynamic design is paging system, displaying a `first previous next last` menu and return data by pages. It is not a very pleasant design for the user as he have to click to display new stuff...